# JSONObject xml conversion error for epoch time

Tags: java, json, xml, epoch

I am writing a program to Convert JSON content which contains epoch time in one of the attribute to XML format and to store it in a string.

Below is the code

```
String data = "{\"result\":\"pass\", \"timestamp\":1497870880.0396869183}";
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data); //the json object contains proper epoch value after this line
String event = XML.toString(json);
```

When i print the content of the string event i get

```
<result>pass</result><timestamp>1.497870880039687E9</timestamp>
```

the value of timestamp is changed.

But if the JSON content has the epoch timestamp as string, like

```
String data = "{\"result\":\"pass\", \"timestamp\":"1497870880.0396869183"}";
```

Then the resultant event string gives proper result

```
<result>pass</result><timestamp>1497870880.0396869183</timestamp>
```

Can anybody please explain why this is happening? Is the JSON XML API not friendly with the LONG values ?
Note: the input JSON content would contain multiple attributes with string values as well as epoch time.

Comment: It's not exactly changing value. It's changing to scientific notation

Comment: Print out the JSONObject before the XML. The problem is probably the json library

Comment: json object has correct and exact epoch value and exact content as the json content. The problem occurs after the toString() call.

Answer (score 0):

JSONObject parses the timestamp as a Double and the scientific notation `1.497870880039687E9` you're seeing is just the result of Double's toString().

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString(double)

> If m is less than 10^3 or greater than or equal to 10^7, then it is represented in so-called "computerized scientific notation." Let n be the unique integer such that 10^n ≤ m < 10^n+1; then let a be the mathematically exact quotient of m and 10^n so that 1 ≤ a < 10. The magnitude is then represented as the integer part of a, as a single decimal digit, followed by '.' ('\u002E'), followed by decimal digits representing the fractional part of a, followed by the letter 'E' ('\u0045'), followed by a representation of n as a decimal integer, as produced by the method Integer.toString(int).

If you want to keep the original format, you need to surround the value in `data` with quotes so JSONObject thinks it's a String.

```
String data = "{\"result\":\"pass\", \"timestamp\":\"1497870880.0396869183\"}";
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could you also mention any ways to avoid that happen within the XML.toString() call?

Comment: @DeepakSelvakumar Other than passing the value around as String, there's no other way. Due to the conversion to Double in JSONObject the timestamp loses precision which is irreversible.